# Replace operation does not function correctly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to replace `'/'` character with `'%252F'` in Brackets. However it returns me `'%2F'`. Although `'%2F'` might mean something similar, I need particularly `'%252F'`. I am wondering how to solve this issue. Below you can see how I am trying to do that.

```
label = '146621/0';
label.replace("/","%252F");
```

Comment: What do you mean by **in Brackets**?

Comment: What Development tool ?

Comment: I think it won't be issue with brackets. Because it's just an editor. I think something else in your script is only making the issue. Could you update your post with more details like from where you are getting `label` value and stuff.

Comment: Where is `%2F` being displayed? In Brackets, in a textbox on your webpage...? `%25` is the character encoding for `%` so this result would be expected in specific scenarios.

Comment: I am using the label var for http request. So %2F displayed in http request string.